# read compressed (zipped) csv with dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Here is my code:

```js
var d = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
    data.csv,
    options);
```

I want to change a simple csv by a csv compressed (zipped) if it's possible!

I wait your answer, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The dygraph library itself doesn´t carry out that task. If you want to do it you have to unzip the file yourself before loading it in the chart